# Puppeteer request interceptor causes net::ERR_FAILED errors with HTTP 30x redirections

Tags: puppeteer, headless-browser

I am trying to get HTML from an URL using Puppeteer without following redirection nor triggering related HTTP requests (CSS, images, etc.).

According to [Puppeteer documentation, we can use `page.setRequestInterception()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue-cachesafe) to ignore some requests.

I also found several *SO* questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46886832/how-to-stop-puppeteer-follow-redirects) that advises to use `request.isNavigationRequest()` and `request.redirectChain()` to determine if request is "main" or a redirection.

So I tried it, but I get `Error: net::ERR_FAILED` errors.

Example with `http://google.com` (which, when requested, answers with a 301 with `Location: http://www.google.com/` header).

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', (interceptedRequest) => {
    if (
        interceptedRequest.isNavigationRequest()
        && interceptedRequest.redirectChain().length !== 0
    ) {
        interceptedRequest.abort();
    } else {
        interceptedRequest.continue();
    }
  });
  await page.goto('http://google.com');
  const html = await page.content();
  console.log(html);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Ran using `node  --trace-warnings file.js`, I get:

```
(node:14252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: net::ERR_FAILED at http://google.com
    at navigate (/path_to_working_dir/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:115:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async FrameManager.navigateFrame (/path_to_working_dir/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:90:21)
    at async Frame.goto (/path_to_working_dir/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:416:16)
    at async Page.goto (/path_to_working_dir/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:789:16)
    at async /path_to_working_dir/file.js:17:3
    at emitUnhandledRejectionWarning (internal/process/promises.js:168:15)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:247:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:32)
(node:14252) Error: net::ERR_FAILED at http://google.com
    at navigate (/path_to_working_dir/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:115:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async FrameManager.navigateFrame (/path_to_working_dir/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:90:21)
    at async Frame.goto (/path_to_working_dir/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:416:16)
    at async Page.goto (/path_to_working_dir/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:789:16)
    at async /path_to_working_dir/file.js:17:3
(node:14252) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    at emitDeprecationWarning (internal/process/promises.js:180:11)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:249:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:32)
```

Using the `http://www.example.com` URL ( instead of `http://google.com`) works fine: no error and I get what a `curl http://www.example.com` would.

How can I discard unwanted redirection requests but still be able to perform actions on the "main" page (`page.screenshot()`, `page.content()`, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

I know this one is a bit old but having encountered the same issue I thought it might still worth sharing how to resolve this issue.

The reason you're getting the `net::ERR_FAILED` error is because after the redirection happens, i.e. `interceptedRequest.redirectChain().length != 0`, `interceptedRequest` which represents the redirected request (i.e. to `https://www.google.com/` in your case) now becomes the main navigation request as is evident by `interceptedRequest.isNavigationRequest()` being `true`, but you then go on to call `abort()` on it. According to [this test spec](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/eefe9583d0f8c8a269c166394c4a192b5a9ed017/test/src/requestinterception.spec.ts#L253) in the Puppeteer source, aborting the main navigation request during a `Page.goto()` will result in a `net::ERR_FAILED` error. The solution is to catch and appropriately handle this error when it is thrown by the `Page.goto()` since it is not unexpected:

```js
try {
    await page.goto('http://google.com');
} catch(e) {
    if (e instanceof Error && e.message.startsWith('net::ERR_FAILED')) {
        console.log('Redirection aborted');
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```